# Как перевернуть таблицу - колонки в строки?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных, pivot

Из такой таблицы:

```
      root_index           word_form
0              2           .ПмИ К6
1              2           .ПмИ СI1
2              3!          .ПмИ СI1
3              2*          .ПмИ К6 СI1
4              6           2 .ПмИ СI1
...          ...           ...
[16210 rows x 2 columns]
```

Получить вот такой результат:

```
2          3!         2*           6
.ПмИ К6    .ПмИ СI1   .ПмИ К6 СI1  2 .ПмИ СI1
.ПмИ СI1
```

Из значений колонки `root_index` сделать колонки в новой таблице. И в этих колонках сгруппировать всё из `word_form`.

Comment: транспонируйте. `df.T`

Comment: Получается 16 тыс колонок.

Comment: Это плохо? Тогда уточните вопрос, какие у вас дополнительные условия для "переворота" таблицы.

Comment: В новой таблице нужно сделать колонки с именами из значений колонки root_index исходной таблицы. Положить в эти новые колонки значения из колонки word_form исходной таблицы.

Comment: `pivot_table` должно подойти https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [DataFrame.pivot_table()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
res = (df
       .assign(idx=df.groupby("root_index").cumcount())
       .pivot_table(index="idx", columns="root_index", 
                    values="word_form", aggfunc="first"))
```

результат:

```
In [298]: res
Out[298]:
root_index         2           2*        3!           6
idx
0            .ПмИ К6  .ПмИ К6 СI1  .ПмИ СI1  2 .ПмИ СI1
1           .ПмИ СI1          NaN       NaN         NaN
```

Comment: cumcount из копипасты остался? )  или тут реально нужно?

Comment: @CrazyElf, нет, он здесь нужен, чтобы получить результат как в вопросе (вторая строка) ;)